# Justification with ng-bootstrap Nav

Tags: ng-bootstrap

Tabset has been removed from ng-bootstrap version 8.0.0.

It is recommended to use Nav directives instead.

Nav does not appear to have a justify attribute or the equivalent functionality.

Has anyone figured out how to add the same justify functionality that was available with Tabsets (start, center, fill, justify, end)?

Answer (score 0):

The ng-bootstrap [Nav docs](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/nav/overview#customization) says:

> It is up to you to specify the nav type using bootstrap standard .nav-tabs or .nav-pills classes. Otherwise active nav will not be highlighted, [similarly to bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/navs/#available-styles).

So you should be able to use bootstrap [flexbox utility](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/#horizontal-alignment) classes like 'justify-content-start'.